# mumble-server i386 depends on libqt4-core and libssl0.9.8

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg

I am trying to use apt-get and i get this error.  It also doesnt allow me to install devs.

```
root@ubuntu:~# sudo apt-get install mumble
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 mumble : Depends: libasound2 (>= 1.0.23)
          Depends: libavahi-compat-libdnssd1 (>= 0.6.16) but it is not going to be installed
          Depends: libg15daemon-client1 but it is not going to be installed
          Depends: libprotobuf7 but it is not going to be installed
          Depends: libpulse0 (>= 1:0.99.1) but it is not going to be installed
          Depends: libqt4-network (>= 4:4.5.3) but it is not going to be installed
          Depends: libqt4-sql (>= 4:4.5.3) but it is not going to be installed
          Depends: libqt4-svg (>= 4:4.5.3) but it is not going to be installed
          Depends: libqtgui4 (>= 4:4.8.0) but it is not going to be installed
          Depends: libsndfile1 (>= 1.0.20) but it is not going to be installed
          Depends: libspeechd2 (>= 0.7.1) but it is not going to be installed
          Depends: libspeex1 (>= 1.2~beta3-1) but it is not going to be installed
          Depends: libspeexdsp1 (>= 1.2~beta3.2-1) but it is not going to be installed
          Depends: gconf2 (>= 2.28.1-2)
          Depends: libqt4-sql-sqlite but it is not going to be installed
          Recommends: speech-dispatcher but it is not going to be installed
 mumble-server:i386 : Depends: libqt4-core:i386 (>= 4.3.2) but it is not going to be installed
                      Depends: libssl0.9.8:i386 (>= 0.9.8e-1) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
root@ubuntu:~# apt-get -f install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  mumble-server:i386
Suggested packages:
  mumble-server-web:i386 mumble-django:i386
The following packages will be upgraded:
  mumble-server:i386
1 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 5 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/958 kB of archives.
After this operation, 2,109 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? y
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of mumble-server:i386:
 mumble-server:i386 depends on libqt4-core (>= 4.3.2).
 mumble-server:i386 depends on libssl0.9.8 (>= 0.9.8e-1).
dpkg: error processing mumble-server:i386 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 mumble-server:i386
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: Edit your qustion and add the output of `sudo dpkg -C` and `apt-cache policy mumble-server:i386 libqt4-core libssl0.9.8`.

Comment: @close-voters Which answer in the original question is same as mine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try these commands on terminal,

```
sudo apt-get purge mumble-server:i386
sudo apt-get install mumble
```